# System.OverflowException in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to make a connection to a MySQL database in VB.Net 2010, the problem here is that the same code worked properly before we changed the server. This is the code:

```
    Private Function Validar_Acceso(ByVal sUsuario As String, ByVal sContrasena As String, ByRef sResultado As String) As Boolean
    Dim bRetorno As Boolean
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario LIKE '" & sUsuario & "'"
    Dim MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection("Server=; Uid=; Pwd=; Database=RepMasivos; Port=3306;")

    Try
        MySqlConn.Open() 'HERE IS THE System.OverflowException

        Dim dbCommand As MySqlCommand = MySqlConn.CreateCommand()
        dbCommand.CommandText = query
        Dim dbReader As MySqlDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If dbReader.Read() Then

            If dbReader("password") = getMD5Hash(sContrasena) Then
                sResultado = dbReader("usuario")
                bRetorno = True
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        sResultado = ex.Message
    Finally
        If MySqlConn IsNot Nothing Then
            MySqlConn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return bRetorno

End Function
```

This is the return error: La operación aritmética ha provocado un desbordamiento.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MySQL did the old serve run, and what version is the new one? and, what version is the mysqlconnector?

Comment: Hello the version on both servers is the "MySQL 5.0.95"